# Can't select unknown attr's with jQuery in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

Each time i try to select a div element with the following selector:

```
div#wl-add-position-steps div[data-step="1"]
```

IE7 can't update the returned object.

```
jQuery('div#wl-add-position-steps div[data-step="1"]').hide();
jQuery('div#wl-add-position-steps div[data-step="2"]').show();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wl-add-position" style="display:none;">
    <div class="wl-description">
        <?php echo $this->translate('wlPositionAddDescription'); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="wl-add-position-steps" class="wl-steps cf">
        <ul>
            <li data-event-step="1" class="active"><span class="a-step"><?php echo $this->translate('stepX', 1); ?></span><?php echo $this->translate('wlPositionStep1'); ?></li>
            <li data-event-step="2"><span class="a-step"><?php echo $this->translate('stepX', 2); ?></span><?php echo $this->translate('wlPositionStep2'); ?></li>
            <li data-event-step="3"><span class="a-step"><?php echo $this->translate('stepX', 3); ?></span><?php echo $this->translate('wlPositionStep3'); ?>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="wl-add-position-steps">
        <div data-step="1">
            <input type="text" class="wl-search-full" id="wl-search-instrument" value="WKN/ISIN/Kürzel/Name" />
            <ul data-block="instruments" class="wl-result-list box twoline activites"></ul>
            <span data-block="nothing-found" style="display:none;">
                <br /><br />
                <img src="/common/img/watchlist-emptylist.png" align="center" class="search-no-warpper" />
            </span>
        </div>
        <div data-step="2" style="display:none;">
            <h3>
                <?php echo $this->translate('wlPostionAddStep3Title'); ?>
            </h3>
            <ul data-block="quoteSources" class="wl-result-list exchanges"></ul>
        </div>
        <div data-step="3" style="display:none;">
            <div class="modal-form-position">
                <div class="cf">
                    <label for="wl-instrument-name"><?php echo $this->translate('value'); ?></label>
                    <input type="text" name="wl-instrument-name" id="wl-instrument-name" readonly value="" />
                </div>

                <div class="cf">
                    <label for="wl-quotesource-name"><?php echo $this->translate('quotesource'); ?></label>
                    <input type="text" name="wl-quotesource-name" id="wl-quotesource-name" readonly value="" />
                </div>

                <div class="cf">
                    <label for="wl-instrument-value"><?php echo $this->translate('buyCourse'); ?></label>
                    <input type="text" name="wl-instrument-value" id="wl-instrument-value" value="" />
                </div>

                <div class="cf">
                    <label for="wl-position-date"><?php echo $this->translate('date'); ?></label>
                    <input type="text" name="wl-position-date" id="wl-position-date" value="<?php echo date('d.m.Y'); ?>" />
                </div>

                <div class="cf">
                    <label for="wl-position-comment"><?php echo $this->translate('comment'); ?></label>
                    <textarea id="wl-position-comment"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this a known problem or just another problem?

Comment: can you provide your html code ?

Comment: No idea if this has anything to do with data attributes. I'd suspect so...

Comment: also remember that you can shorten the syntax, instead of jQuery just write $

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code, but it would depend on the HTML code.

Comment: @BerggreenDK: It'd conflict if he were using jQuery with other libraries that depend on `$`.

Comment: I have just tested this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tq8ea/ in IE6 and 7 and it is working.. Could you elaborate a bit more on your HTML structure? Is it the same as I have assumed in that jsFiddle?

Comment: Ok but there is no other library who use $. ExtJs is using Ext.

Comment: I've add the html block.

Comment: did u try with `>` like `jQuery('div#wl-add-position-steps>div[data-step="1"]').hide();`

Comment: Ok the problem is simple to fix. IE7 can't read direct children() of an element. So the selector can't get the element div#wl-add-position-steps>div[data-step="1"]. 

With the select: [data-step="1"]. The issue is corrected!

Comment: As an aside, you should replace `div#wl-add-position-steps` with `#wl-add-position-steps` as the selector will be *much* faster as it will now be able to use the browsers `getElementById` method.

Comment: Your selector `jQuery('div#wl-add-position-steps div[data-step="1"]')` is more efficiently written as: `jQuery('#wl-add-position-steps').find('div[data-step="1"]')` due to the right to left selector processing in the sizzle engine.

Answer (score 0):

> Ok the problem is simple to fix. IE7 can't read direct children() of an element. So the selector can't get the element div#wl-add-position-steps>div[data-step="1"]. With the select: [data-step="1"]. The issue is corrected!